# How do I read a text file's contents and return a string between two strings I specify?

Tags: c

Here is `example.txt`:

```
##TITLE
My program
# 1
# 2
##
```

So far, I have a function that reads the whole file and returns its contents in a `char*`.

```
char *getTextBlock(const char *filename, char *textBlockLabel){
    char *fileContents;
    long fileSize;
    FILE *fp=   fopen(filename,"r");

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileSize=   ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    fileContents=   malloc(fileSize * sizeof(char));
    fread(fileContents, sizeof(char), fileSize, fp);

    fclose(fp);
    return fileContents;
}
```

When I run this program, this function would be `getTextBlock("example.txt","##TITLE");`.

I want to get and return everything between `##TITLE` and `##` in `example.txt`.

In this case, that would mean:

```
My program
# 1
# 2
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `How do I do this?` --> Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: As `"##TITLE"` does not include the end of line, I'd expect the output to begin with the end-of-line that followed `##TITLE`. So output would be `"\nMy program\n# 1\n..."`

Comment: In your function I do not see the second pattern ("##")

Comment: Are you specifically looking to return lines (as opposed to words or characters)?  To put it another way, if the first like of that example file were `##TITLE SomeText`, should `"SomeText"` be part of your output?  Your use of the phrase `TextBlock` suggests you want to operate on lines at a time.  If so, you might be best off splitting your file into an array of one-line strings, making your unit of information "line of text"; at the moment, it's "character".  (Also, your `getTextBlock` function should probably take a third argument: something like `textBlockEnd`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* getTextBlock(const char *filename, char *textBlockLabel){
    char *fileContents;

    FILE * pFile;
    long lSize;
    char * buffer;
    size_t result;

    pFile = fopen (filename , "r" );
    if (pFile==NULL) {
        fputs ("File error",stderr);
        return NULL;
    }

    // obtain file size:
    fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell (pFile);
    rewind (pFile);

    // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
    buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        fputs ("Memory error",stderr);
        return NULL;
    }

    // copy the file into the buffer:
    result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);
    if (result != (unsigned long)lSize) {
        fputs ("Reading error",stderr);
        return NULL;
    }

    fileContents = strstr(buffer, textBlockLabel);
    if(fileContents!= NULL)
        fileContents+= strlen(textBlockLabel);

    fclose(pFile);

    free (buffer);

    return fileContents;
}

int main()
{
    char * content = getTextBlock("example.txt","##TITLE");
    if(content != NULL)
        printf("%s", content);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
My program
# 1
# 2
##
```

With 2 patterns:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* getTextBlock(const char *filename, char *start, char *stop){
    char *fileContents;

    FILE * pFile;
    long lSize;
    char * buffer;
    size_t result;

    pFile = fopen (filename , "r" );
    if (pFile==NULL) {
        fputs ("File error",stderr);
        return NULL;
    }

    // obtain file size:
    fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell (pFile);
    rewind (pFile);

    // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
    buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        fputs ("Memory error",stderr);
        return NULL;
    }

    // copy the file into the buffer:
    result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);
    if (result != (unsigned long)lSize) {
        fputs ("Reading error",stderr);
        return NULL;
    }

    fileContents = strstr(buffer, start);
    if(fileContents!= NULL)
        fileContents+= strlen(start);

    char *end = strstr(fileContents, stop);
    if(end == NULL)
        return NULL;
    end[0]= '\0';

    fclose(pFile);

    free (buffer);

    return fileContents;
}

int main()
{
    char * content = getTextBlock("example.txt","##TITLE", "##");
    if(content != NULL)
        printf("%s", content);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
My program
# 1
# 2
```

Comment: Curious, why use type `unsigned long lSize;.... lSize = ftell (pFile);` when `ftell()` returns `long`?

Comment: @chux update my code

Comment: if `sizeof(char)` is `1`, could we not just write instead `buffer = malloc(lSize);`?

Comment: @RoadRunner For me it is only custom: (type *) malloc (sizeof (type) * length);

Comment: `free (buffer); return fileContents;` ????

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what is your question?

Comment: Do not use an area that has already been `free`'d.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY The pointer is deallocated by pointer, ie I have freed the buffer memory, but will keep the assignment of fileContents.

Comment: It's undefined behavior.

Comment: For `strstr` to work properly in all cases, your `buffer` should be null-terminated.

Comment: Make memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is once you get the file content in a string you can do this thing

```
    char *begin,*end;
    begin= strstr( s, pattern) // ##TITLE
    char *op = NULL;
    if ( begin !=NULL )
    {
        begin += strlen( pattern);
        end = strstr( begin, pattern1); // ##
        if (end!=NULL )
        {
            op= malloc( end- begin+ 1 );
            if(op == NULL)
            { 
               printf("%s","ERROR in Allocation");
               // if you use in function return or show message
            }
            else
            {
               memcpy( op, begin, end- begin);
               op[end - begin] = '\0';
               //print op or what you want
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
       // first pattern not found. return empty string or show message
    }
```

Most help from **Vlad from Moscow** .
This was his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696113/how-to-find-text-between-two-strings-in-c). From this I used it months ago..and stored in my machine. Now I used again.

### Explanation of the code

This code exactly doing the thing as we would do if we are asked to do the task

- So at first, we are trying to find out the first "TITLE##" from the string which contains everything that the file contains.
- If we don't find it then the program will print nothing or possibly return an empty string.
- If the the first `strstr` returns not `NULL` then we have found it. We will again start searching. But where do we start? we need to start from the end of first pattern's occurrence otherwise we will find the `##` from `TITLE##` itself which is not we want.
- so we correctly set the pointer and then again do a search for second pattern.
- If found then we will just allocate a string of size `end-begin+1` that extra space `1` is for keeping the `\0` or end of string marker.
- We need to check return value of `malloc` whether it is successful or not.

<sub>Note: It is better to termiante the string with `NUL` and my code assumes that. Just put `\0` end of the string where you gather everything of the file.</sub>